# APNS TestFlight vs Development delivery rate

Tags: swift, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, testflight

I am working on an EventKit app where I need some mechanism for refreshing UserNotifications in the background and during development I found silent push notifications to be much more reliable than a BGAPPRefreshTask. In a development environment (i.e. running the app) they get delivered every hour almost without exception. When building for TestFlight however, the exact same setup results in the silent push being delivered only a few times a day. Apple's documentation states:

> The system treats background notifications as low priority: you can
> use them to refresh your app’s content, but the system doesn’t
> guarantee their delivery. In addition, the system may throttle the
> delivery of background notifications if the total number becomes
> excessive. The number of background notifications allowed by the
> system depends on current conditions, but don’t try to send more than
> two or three per hour.

So while I understand they are not guaranteed and I should try to not exceed 2-3 per hour (I am sending 1 per hour), I would still like to understand what causes this discrepancy between Dev and TestFlight and if there is anything I could do to improve deliverability rate.

I am using FCM to send these notifications and they are configured as follows. I have tried 'apns-priority': '5' also and it made no difference.

```
exports.sendSilentPush = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 * * * *').onRun(async () => {
    const message = {
        topic: "refreshNotifications",
        apns: {
            headers: {
                'apns-priority': '10',
                'apns-push-type': 'background'
            },
            payload: {
                aps: {
                    'content-available' : 1
                },
            }
        }
    };

    try {
        const response = await messaging.send(message);
        console.log('Notifications sent successfully.', response);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error sending notifications', error);
    }
});
```

In my app, I am registering for the FCM topic then implementing didReceiveRemoteNotification

import UIKit
import FirebaseMessaging

```
extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
    private func registerForTopic() {
        if !UserDefaults.registeredForFCMTopic {
            Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "refreshNotifications") { error in
                if let error = error { print("Failed to subscribe to refreshNotifications topic: \(error.localizedDescription)") }
                else {
                    UserDefaults.registeredForFCMTopic = true
                    Firebase.log("Registered for FCM Topic")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
        // This delegate method will be called every time the fcm token is retrieved, or changed.
        guard fcmToken != nil else { return }
        registerForTopic()
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        registerForTopic()
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        let log = "Failed to register for remote notifications with error: \(error)"
        Firebase.log(log)
    }
}

extension AppDelegate {
    // This code gets called when a silent push notification is received
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        EK.shared.eventStore.refreshSourcesIfNecessary()
        Firebase.log("Silent push received")

        if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active {
            completionHandler(.noData)
            return
        }
        
        if let lastRefreshDate = UserDefaults.lastNotificationsRefreshDate, !lastRefreshDate.isOlderThanTenMinutes {
            Firebase.log("Silent push received, but lastNotificationsRefreshDate was \(lastRefreshDate.description(with: .current))")
            completionHandler(.noData)
            return
        }
        
        Task.detached {
            do {
                try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 5 * 1_000_000_000)
                try await DataStorage.getCalendarsAndEvents()
                await DataStorage.updatePendingInvites()
                UserNotifications.setBadgeNumber()
                UserNotifications.updateNotifications(from: "Silent push")
                
                UserNotifications.getActive() { notifications in
                    Firebase.log("Notifications updated: \(notifications.count)", notifications: notifications)
                }
                UserDefaults.lastNotificationsRefreshDate = Date()
                completionHandler(.newData)
            } catch {
                Firebase.log("There was an error with the silent push. Error: \(error)")
                completionHandler(.failed)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In Firebase I have FCM configured with an APNS Auth Key
[image]

And I believe I have everything set up correctly in Xcode
[image]
[image]
[image]

What I wanted to ask is if there is anything that I could do to make silent push notifications in a production environment like TestFlight have a delivery rate closer to that of the Dev environment.

Thank you.